Jira Server Endpoint not returning Changelog
I am using Jira server and calling https://jira.xxxx/rest/agile/1.0/issue/SPTCOU-42?%20expand=changelog in order to extract the history of a particular issue so that I can calculate the amount of time a ticket was in each status to work out the adherence to the SLA.
The challenge is that the "history" data is not returned. It is returning all the worklogs (which I haven't asked for as that should be a separate endpoint) but not the changelog.
Any ideas?

You're using the wrong endpoint. You need to use the Get Issue endpoint of Jira Server, not Jira SOFTWARE Server.
Use https://jira.xxxx/rest/2/issue/SPTCOU-42?expand=changelog
